# Passing all the record fields on ng-click Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following data i get using factory in angular.

```
$scope.data=[{actId:12, acctName: "Tom James"}, {acctId:20, acctName: "Lisa Anderson"}]
```

In my html code I am using ng-repeat to display just the name.

```
<div ng-repeat=" record in data">
<div>{{record.acctName}}</div>
<div><button ng-click="getDetails(record)">Get Details</div>
</div>
```

In my controller I have

```
$scope.getDetails=function(record)
{
   alert(record.actId)
}
```

In my controller I am trying to see if acctId is passed I get undefined error. Please let me know how I can pass the current record with all of its fields.
Thanks

Comment: You're having `actId` for the first record and `acctId` for second, this is the reason you're getting `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get actId then you have to pass actId in getDetails function.

```
<div ng-repeat=" record in data">
<div>{{record.acctName}}</div>
<div><button ng-click="getDetails(record.actId)">Get Details</div>
</div>
```

in Controller

```
$scope.getDetails=function(actId)
{
   alert(actId);
}
```

If you want to pass both accName and actId then here is the code for do this:-

```
<div ng-repeat=" record in data">
<div>{{record.acctName}}</div>
<div><button ng-click="getDetails(record.acctName,record.actId)">Get Details</div>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.getDetails=function(acName,actId)
{
   alert(acName);// this is for name
   alert(actId); //For Id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is spelling mistake use  `record.actId` insted of  `record.acctId`